# How do you stop an Observable.Timer()?

Tags: .net, f#, system.reactive

If an Observable is created using `Observable.Timer()`, how do you stop it?

```fs
let tmr = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds 1000.)
let subscription = tmr.Subscribe(myFunction)
// ...
subscription.Dispose()
```

Do you even need to stop it, or will it be garbage collected when all its subscribers have been disposed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The timer doesn't even start "firing" until you subscribe to it (what you would call a "[cold observable](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html)"). Moreover: it will start firing as many times as there are subscriptions to it. Try this:

```
let tmr = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds 1000.)
let subscription = tmr.Subscribe(printfn "A: %d")
Thread.Sleep 500
let subscription2 = tmr.Subscribe(printfn "B: %d")
```

This program will print `A: 1`, then `B: 1`, then `A: 2`, then `B: 2`, and so on - roughly every 500 milliseconds.

Consequently, the timer does stop "firing" as soon as the subscription is disposed. But only that particular timer, not all of them.

One way to think about your `tmr` object is as a "timer factory", not a "timer" as such.

Comment: If all subscriptions are disposed and the "timer factory" itself is not pinned to a value anymore, will it be garbage collected?

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Is there any reference source for information like this? I cannot see information in [Observable.Timer's docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.timer(v=vs.103).aspx) whether it creates a hot or cold observable.

Comment: @JohnReynolds: yes, it will be garbage collected, of course; just like any other object.

Comment: @TomaszMaczyński: when the documentation is unhelpful, I usually use experimentation (like the above) or [source code](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/1ad21f5a853f2b7be5f3a7e4a8d276e7d28f0d73/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Time.cs#L1517) (or ILSpy when source is not available).

Comment: @FyodorSoikin thanks. I hoped that there's some rule (e.g. that observables are cold unless documented otherwise).

Comment: @TomaszMaczyński: You can make up a rule, no problem, but how do you force the library writers to obey it?

Comment: @TomaszMaczyński - Yes, the rule is pretty much that observables are cold unless stated otherwise. There are very few hot observables.

Comment: @TomaszMaczyński this is "documented" on IntroToRx.com. Seehttp://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableTimer and http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#HotObservables. Examples in C#.

Comment: I believe the docs are getting more attention now and will may take contributions from the community soon.